# Using libcurl to get meaning from owlbot via a c program

Tags: c, json, dictionary, header, libcurl

I want to write a c program using the libcurl that is equivalent to this command on a Unix terminal:
`curl --header "Authorization: Token <I placed the key over here without these "<>">" https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/owl -s | json_pp`

Below is my code was written using other posts and reading the documentation of the library.
But I get an error from the server as follows:
`{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<curl/curl.h>

int main(){
  //initializes some of libcurl functionality globally
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  
  CURLcode res;
  /*creates an easy handle for using the easy interface.
   *A handle is a logic entity for the upcoming transfer or series of transfer */
  CURL *easyhandle;
  easyhandle = curl_easy_init();

  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  curl_slist_append(headers,"Authorization: Token <I placed the key over here without these "<>">");
  curl_slist_append(headers,"Content-Type:text/json");
    //Pass the list of custom made headers
  curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
 curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle,CURLOPT_URL,"https://owlbot.info/api/v4/dictionary/owl");

  
 
  res = curl_easy_perform(easyhandle);
  curl_easy_cleanup(easyhandle);
  curl_global_cleanup();
  
}
```

Comment: Probably not your issue, but I think you need an `accept` header, not `content-type`. `content-type` describes the body (of a request or a response) and `GET` requests have no body.

Comment: `curl_slist_append` returns the *new pointer* that you should then use to pass in to the next call and eventually to the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option!

Comment: @DanielStenberg I do understand what you are saying till some extent but not really. 
can you please rewrite that part of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that creates the custom headers need to pass on the `headers` variable correctly since [curl_slist_append](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_slist_append.html) returns **the new pointer**.

A fixed version of that little section probably looks similar to this:

```c
  struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Token <I placed the key over here without these "<>">");
  headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type:text/json");
  curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it Worked!